# Cartesian tensor gradient

Tags: tensors, calculus-and-analysis

Let $\mathbf{R} = [x,y,z]$ be a cartesian vector, $R_\alpha$ it's tensor representation with $\alpha = x,y,z$ and let $R=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ be its norm. I want to do tensor derivatives of the Coulomb potential $1/R$. The first derivative is $\frac{\partial}{\partial R_\alpha} \frac{1}{R} = -\frac{R_\alpha}{R^3}$ and the second derivative is $\frac{\partial}{\partial R_\beta} \frac{\partial}{\partial R_\alpha}  \frac{1}{R}= \frac{\delta_{\alpha\beta}R^2 - R_\alpha R_\beta }{R^5}$. I want to make further derivatives in Mathematica.

I tried

```
R = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]
```

$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$

```
rR = 1/R
```

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$

```
drR = Grad[rR, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"]
```

$\{-\frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}, -\frac{y}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}, -\frac{z}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} \}$

So can I make Mathematica identify the denominators as $R^3$ and the numerators as $R_\alpha$ and get it to the compact form $-\frac{R_\alpha}{R^3}$, or is there some other way to do tensor calculus/arithmetics compactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following will suffice?

```
R /: D[R, R[α_], NonConstants->{R}] := R[α]/R
R /: D[R[α_], R[β_], NonConstants->{R}] := KroneckerDelta[α, β]

R /: MakeBoxes[R[α_], fmt_] := MakeBoxes[Subscript[R,α], fmt]
```

Your examples:

```
D[1/R, R[α], NonConstants->{R}] //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{R_{\alpha }}{R^3}$

```
D[1/R, R[α], R[β], NonConstants->{R}] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{3 R_{\alpha } R_{\beta }}{R^5}-\frac{\delta _{\alpha ,\beta }}{R^3}$

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks a lot! Maybe you put in Clear[R] at the top, because I didn't get it to work first since $R$ was already defined in the notebook.