# Tensor calculations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, tensors

During my current work, I want to calculate expression
$\nabla_{\gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\nabla_{\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{R}\right)$,
where $R\equiv\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are 3D-indices (1,2,3) and metric is euclidean, $\nabla_{\alpha}\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}$. I try to use Ricci package, but I did not find any suitable examples in documentation. Does anybody try to calculate expressions like that?

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_software I find some similar packages, but I have not got enough experience in Mathematica and can not choose the simplest way to solve my problem.

Comment: Why not do this: `Table[D[Sqrt[x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2], x[α], x[β], 
  x[γ]], {α, 3}, {β, 3}, {γ 3}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can use my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143430/45431) to [Cartesian tensor gradient](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143409/45431)? For instance:

```
D[1/R, R[α], R[β], R[γ], NonConstants->{R}] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{3 R_{\alpha } \delta _{\beta ,\gamma }}{R^5}+\frac{3 R_{\beta } \delta _{\alpha
>    ,\gamma }}{R^5}+\frac{3 R_{\gamma } \delta _{\alpha ,\beta }}{R^5}-\frac{15 R_{\alpha
>    } R_{\beta } R_{\gamma }}{R^7}$

Comment: Sorry me, I really tried to find answer, but it was unsuccesful.

Wonderful!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: In addition, where I can find information/guides about these Mathematica features?