# Manipulations with tensors that keep so(3,1) symmetry manifest

Tags: tensors, vector-calculus, xact

I am doing some manipulations with tensors in curved background. There are, however, coordinates, where Lorentz symmetry is manifest. So, on one hand, I am dealing with particular coordinates and, on the other hand, I don't want to deal with tensors component by component, because there is Lorentz symmetry around that simplifies things.

For example, we have a vector field of the form
$$A_\mu = a_{\mu}F(x^\nu x_\nu,x^\lambda b_\lambda)$$
where $a_\mu$ and $b_\lambda$ are constant covectors and $x^\nu$ is a coordinate and $F$ - some unknown function of scalar arguments. I would like to be able to evaluate efficiently expressions like $D_\mu A_\nu$ where the Christoffel symbols are also expressed in terms of $x^\mu$ and some constant parameters/Lorentz vectors (it would be nice to implement evaluation of the Christoffel symbols automatically, but anyway I already computed them). In computations, I would like Mathematica to do things like
$$\partial_\mu F(x^2,bx)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^2}2x_\mu + \frac{\partial F}{\partial bx}b_\mu, \qquad \partial_\mu x^\nu =\delta^\nu_{\mu}$$
and so on and then to be able to contract indices.
What is the best way to achieve that? I assume, I can use xCoba and introduce (co)vector fields for $a$, $x$ and $b$. But then Mathematica will not take into account, for example, that $\partial_\mu a_\nu =0$ unless I assign to $a_\mu$'s components some constant values $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ and $a_4$. On the other hand, if I do assign some concrete values to the components, I am afraid, I will get $a^\mu b_\mu$ in the form $a^1b_1+a^2b_2+a^3b_3+a^4b_4$, which is a mess. Or, may be it is better to deal with Mathematica's built in tensor manipulations?

I looked through suggested similar questions and it seems that
[Cartesian tensor gradient](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143409/cartesian-tensor-gradient) will do the job with differentiation. Essentially, to the best of my understanding, I am supposed to teach Mathematica how derivatives act on each expression that one encounters. But then I will also need to contract indices, e.g.
$$x^\mu\eta_{\mu\nu}\to x_\nu, \qquad x^\mu x^\mu \eta_{\mu\nu} \to x^2.$$
Should I also then teach Mathematica all contraction rules? How does it work in practice?

Comment: There’s a Mathematica package called xAct that will help you with this. Try it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I am studying it right now. xCoba that I mentioned above is a part of xAct that allows to work in particular coordinates. But so far it seems that xAct allows to work either in a completely coordinate-independent manner, which would not let me substituting concrete expressions for tensor fields (because this breaks diffeos) or one can substitute expressions in particular coordinates using xCoba, but then I am lead to deal with components, which does not take into account simplifications arising from residual Lorentz symmetry. But I keep reading, may be I will find the right tool :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a situation like this, the best way to proceed in xAct is to use xTensor only:

```
<<xAct`xTensor`
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices;
```

I use here Latin indices, but you can easily change all of this to use Greek indices:

```
DefManifold[M, 4, {a, b, c, d}]

DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], CD]

DefTensor[A[c], M]
DefTensor[B[c], M]
DefTensor[x[c], M]

DefScalarFunction[F]
```

Declare the differentiation properties of those objects:

```
x /: PD[a_][x[b_]] := delta[a, b]
A /: PD[a_][A[b_]] := 0
B /: PD[a_][B[b_]] := 0
```

Construct the scalars you need:

```
x2 = x[-a] x[a];
Bx = B[-a] x[a];
```

Now you can perform the operation you wanted, with the result you wanted:

```
PD[-a][F[x2, Bx]] // ContractMetric
```

This is how the result looks in output:

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!